# getting error in create a new project using csxjs, vite and react to create a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, jsx, vite

main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

i'm getting this error while following all the official guide in csxjs

Answer (score 1):

When you load your unpacked extension in chrome, choose the /dist folder which contains the compiled version of your react app.
[/dist folder in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEOzr.png)